# How to parse Riot Games API response

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

I am trying to make a simple app with Xamarin and the Riot Games API. I have trouble accessing summoner information. It works only with my username due to the way that my deserialization is done I think.

This is my code:

```
public async void GetSummonerInformation()
{
     using (var client = new HttpClient())
     {
     var result = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
     var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
     sumName = res.psychoal3x.name;
     }

}
public class Psychoal3x
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int profileIconId { get; set; }
    public int summonerLevel { get; set; }
    public long revisionDate { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Psychoal3x psychoal3x { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that if I change my username to something else then it won't work since it will search for `psychoal3x` in the RootObject class. Anyone know how to fix this?

EDIT

Ok so i changed the code a bit and this is how it looks like

This is the modified code

```
  try
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result;
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, SummonerDto>>(result);
                var name1 = data.First().Value.name;
                var id = data.First().Value.id;
                var profileIconId1 = data.First().Value.profileIconId;
                var revisionDate1 = data.First().Value.revisionDate;
                sumId = id;
                sumProfileIconId = profileIconId1;
                sumRevisionDate = revisionDate1;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0} this is the  {1}", data.First().Value.name, data.First().Value.profileIconId);
            }
        }catch(Exception ex)
        { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
    public class SummonerDto
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int profileIconId { get; set; }
        public int summonerLevel { get; set; }
        public long revisionDate { get; set; }

    }
```

where sumName is the account name that is changed when the api is called.

Comment: I made a couple clients for this when the v1.0 API came out. However that was a year or so ago and it would need updated. Here they are though!

https://github.com/JonDouglas/LoLFit / https://github.com/JonDouglas/LoLRank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, but don't hardcode the username into your model classes. Assuming the API you are calling is [this one](https://developer.riotgames.com/api/methods#!/1221/4746), I'd recommend a structure like this:

```
public class SummonerDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ProfileIconId { get; set; }
    public int SummonerLevel { get; set; }
    public long RevisionDate { get; set; }
}
```

According to the API docs, the return type is `Dictionary<string, SummonerDto>`. You can use JSON.NET to deserialize this easily:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, SummonerDto>>(result);
```

That means that there will be a key-value pair with the key `"psychoal3x"` and a `SummonerDto` object as the value. You can get the first returned value by using `First()`:

```
var summoner = data.First().Value;
```

From there, you can access all the properties, such as `Name`.

Here's a working fiddle based on the JSON data you posted in the comments: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xEUXa6

Comment: Hello,

i don't think this is the solution that i am looking for.
First of all,it gives an error in data[0].Name that an int cannot be converted to a string.Second,that wouldn't solve(i think)the problem that i have with the different account names.This is the json that is returned when called the api:
`{
   "psychoal3x":{
      "id":36564871,
      "name":"PsychoAl3x",
      "profileIconId":1394,
      "summonerLevel":30,
      "revisionDate":1481230226000
   }
}`
The problem is that i want to search for different usernames but it can only search for psychoal3x.

Comment: I think i fixed it!Check my answer below

Comment: @AlexTselikas I fixed a problem in my answer - does this work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately yours doesnt work.I have to import System.Linq to recognise the First() but then i couldn't get add my properties.I could only put Equals,GetHashCode,GetType,Key,ToString and Value after the data.First().

Comment: @AlexTselikas Sorry, I screwed up the syntax. I need more coffee :) fixed!

Comment: @AlexTselikas Great! If my answer was, helpful, can you vote it up and click the checkmark to accept it?